# Is there any way to remove dead replicas in solrcloud?

Tags: solr, apache-zookeeper, solrcloud

I am using solr 4.5. After several tests I have noticed a lot of dead (non existing) replicas are shown in my SolrCloud graph as gone (black). Is there any way to force my solr to forget about this gone replicas?

I think that manually modifying /clusterstate.json node in zookeeper might help but did not try it yet.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The simplest way I found is in fact editing /clusterstate.json in zookeeper, and removing dead replicas info from it.

Comment: Worth noticing is a nice lightweight zookeeper editor I found on github [zkNavigator](https://github.com/looprock/zkNavigator)

Answer (score 3):

I don't know if there is any way to do some sort of global cleanup... but:

- There is an API to remove some specific replica:
  https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Collections+API#CollectionsAPI-DeleteaReplica
- As well as for removing the (INACTIVE) shard with all it's replica's (4.4+):
  https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Collections+API#CollectionsAPI-DeleteaShard

And, if this is something related to production and not only for testing purpose - you may also want to look at this upcoming change from 4.6 related to registering the replica that was previously removed - https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-5311

Comment: DeleteaReplica API command would be exactly what I need. I have only several dead replicas so I could delete all them manually. However according to wiki you mentioned this command was introduced in solr 4.6 which I am not going to use until it's released. On the other hand DeleteaShard documentation suggests, that it's removing shard info from  clusterstate.json. So I will try to edit that file manually to see if it works (as soon as my zooinpector starts working)